# How to web scrape a dynamic website in Google Colab?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I initialized webdriver for chrome but session is not created it failed.

**Error:SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

def get_pubchem_ids(search_term):
    base_url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/"
    search_url = f"{base_url}#query={search_term}"

# Initialize Selenium WebDriver (Chrome)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(search_url)

# Wait for some time (adjust as necessary)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a[@class="f-medium" and contains(@href, "compound")][@data-action="result-link"][@data-label="Result Secondary Link; Position:1; Page:1"]//span[@class="breakword"]/span')

    driver.quit()
```